# Since there is no absolute reference frame, and if there were only two, how would the two bodies know whether to fall or orbit?

Tags: gravity

Imagine the earth and a satellite in geostationary orbit. Now subtract the rest of the universe, with nothing else to frame the velocity, and from a certain point of view the two bodies seem to be simply sitting stationary with no apparent force holding them apart. So they break gravity.

Edit 1:
With or with out the rest of the universe, it should be the inertia of the satellite due to it's velocity that is holding it up. But with out the  universe I don't see how you can determine a velocity. I'm not trying to troll, I'm legitimately confused.

Edit 2:
To say a thing is accelerating, you must specify what it is accelerating in reference to. If you think the rotating reference frame is non inertial, then you are probably still imagining the rest of the universe and/or some kind of absolute reference frame, which does not exist.

Edit 3:
I've slept on it, and I feel like I understand this so much better now. Thank you all for the dialog.
However *I am still confused* on some things. For one, I thought Einsteins theories required that we do away with "preferred reference frames" but I kind of get the inkling from the dialog on this question that we are preferring some reference frame... perhaps I am not understanding that correctly? I did some small research on that this morning and dug up a thing on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity#Lack_of_an_absolute_reference_frame

> The principle of relativity, which states that there is no preferred inertial reference frame, dates back to Galileo, and was incorporated into Newtonian physics. However, in the late 19th century, the existence of electromagnetic waves led physicists to suggest that the universe was filled with a substance that they called "aether", which would act as the medium through which these waves, or vibrations travelled. The aether was thought to constitute an absolute reference frame against which speeds could be measured, and could be considered fixed and motionless. Aether supposedly possessed some wonderful properties: it was sufficiently elastic to support electromagnetic waves, and those waves could interact with matter, yet it offered no resistance to bodies passing through it. The results of various experiments, including the Michelson–Morley experiment, led to the theory of special relativity, by showing that there was no aether.[21] Einstein's solution was to discard the notion of an aether and the absolute state of rest. In relativity, any reference frame moving with uniform motion will observe the same laws of physics. In particular, the speed of light in vacuum is always measured to be c, even when measured by multiple systems that are moving at different (but constant) velocities.

Contrast that with garyp's comment

> You have two bodies interacting by gravity, and nothing else in the universe. There is exactly one frame of reference in which the centripetal acceleration is compatible with the force of gravity. We might call that a "non rotating" frame. So the question is: what are the other frames rotating with respect to? – garyp

Well basically I am now wondering if the speed of light gives us some clue as to which frames are or are not rotating? Does Einstein have an answer to the conundrum?

Comment: The bodies would only appear to be stationary in a rotating frame, which is non-inertial. In non-inertial frames [fictitious forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force) appear, and it would be a fictitious force holding the two bodies apart. Gravity wouldn't be broken.

Comment: I'm not sure why the question was downvoted. It's a reasonable question. I've only posted a comment because right now I don't have time to write a full answer.

Comment: But what makes the rotating frame any less valid than any other frame? How can you tell which frame is rotating if there is only two points?

Comment: Yeah I don't know why it's getting down voted either. :/

Comment: Well you've now edited your question to include [Mach's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach%27s_principle) and/or [Newton's bucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_argument), both of which stray dangerously close to intellectual masturbation.

Comment: hahaha "intellectual masturbation"

Comment: It wasn't meant to be a joke.

Comment: Joke or no, it got Einstein thinking.

Comment: I agree with @JohnRennie.  Why the downvotes?

Comment: There is no preferred 'inertial' frame of reference. There's a difference between inertial frames and non-inertial frames.

Comment: I mean how proposterous is it, for someone considering this "mental masterbation" alone, and absolute motion relative the whole universe, and gravity having some similarities to ficitious inertial forces. And after some work all the sudden it near perfectly explain pertubations in orbits, and even time dialation for gps etc. It's insane. And it all comes down to coordinate systems, differential geometry almost pure geometry alone.

Comment: I mean additionally if gravity was a central force field similar to some non inertial reference frames, describe quite well by curvilinear coordiantes which are local vectors (tangent bundles yet math people who deal with high level proofs on the topic can't realize this), now we consider that electrostatic force is the same thing. Same mathematically. Interstingly you throw magnatism in there too.

Answer (score 0):

The only time you cannot define a velocity is if you only have one body in the universe. Two and more bodies define a center of mass and a velocity vector with respect to the center of mass.

Two bodies will be rotating about the center of mass if there exists an angular momentum. Conservation of angular momentum makes the orbits stable . If no initial angular momentum exists they will fall on each other by the attraction of gravity.

One determines a velocity by measuring the dx/dt dy/dt dz/dt of , for example, the satellite with respect to a system where the earth is at rest. One can then transform everything to the center of mass of the two body system. For a satellite within errors the center of mass is the center of the earth, due to the huge difference in the masses, so it is even simpler.

Comment: You have two bodies interacting by gravity, and nothing else in the universe.  There is exactly one frame of reference in which the centripetal acceleration  is compatible with the force of gravity.  We might call that a "non rotating" frame.  So the question is:  what are the other frames rotating with respect to?

Answer (score 0):

I was taught that the first Newton's law should be seen as a definition of an inertial frame and a postulate that there exists such a frame.

If you were observing the two bodies mentioned in your post and believed in "our gravity", you would think that this "theory of gravity" is probably not true, since the bodies behave much differently than described.

But what the first Newton's law would say is you could change your frame (change your speed, gain acceleration, jerk, …, rotation, whatever is possible to change a reference frame), be in luck and find yourself in a frame where some laws (Newton's) seem to be true, and Newton would name it an intertial frame.

---

We think that Newton's laws sound natural, reasonable, that we "work" in so-called inertial frames. It does not bother us that there is no one absolute, canonical frame (ex. *the inertial frame*). We assume there exists at least one frame where we can easily describe things, then someone can transform our results to his frame and tell they seem to be true from his point of view too.

But all the "physical laws" are our guesses. In one given frame we guess some laws, we also guess laws of transformations to all other frames we can think of. We are happy that long-developed descriptions in terms of inertial frames, gravity, etc. give some not bad approximations of what we see happen in this world. Some people think that laws are natural, but it still only an opinion. Someone can think of the Ptolemaic system as more natural and its orbits as more pretty.

If you were in the frame described in your post, you could still develop other descriptions of so-called physics. Maybe they would be as good as "ours", but to know that, we would have to predict other effects observable in both frames and compare - experiment. (But if your world is just the two bodies standing still and nothing else can be observed, there is no need to rotate your frame and develop some "gravity". "The only two bodies stand still" would be the theory of everything.)

Answer (score 0):

The bodies don't 'know' anything. If at t=0, the bodies had sufficient velocities relative to each other, the bodies would orbit their centre of mass and if at t=0 the bodies were still with respect to each other, the bodies would fall towards each other. There's still no absolute frame of reference and if you pick any inertial frame of reference, you would still observe the bodies following the laws of motion and gravity.